# Error on server - FIle or assembly load issue

Tags: asp.net, moles

I am getting the following error on server-

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Moles.Framework, Version=0.94.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The strange thing is it is not consistent. On deploying the bin again the error disappears and reappears randomly again.

The other random error which occurs in similar way:

> The requested script resource 'Common.Common.js' requires version 'AjaxControlToolKit, version=4.1.40412.0 culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework. To use this resource, make sure that the softwarereferences version
>   'AjaxControlToolKit, version=4.1.40412.0 culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'

Although I do not have any JSS with this name or used in the application.

Comment: You could have given better question name!

Comment: sorry..I know..I am just too stressed..:(

Comment: may you please explain more that when you got this type of error...

it's difficult if you do not clear the question.

Comment: Are you using Ajax ToolKit..

Comment: yes..I am..but these are two different errors..both coming randomly..on few pages..on load only..and just getting resolved by redeploying the bin folder without any changes..which is weird.

Comment: This means that your deployment not copying bin folder properly.

Comment: We just copy paste published folder. And if so once it runs fine why does it start throwing error randomly after that.